# Is Spark read csv a lazy operation or eager?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've read some resources claiming that Spark read operations are generally lazy. But I've run some jobs that took a long time on the csv read step. Then I read this article saying csv read is an eager operation[1]. Do you have a more definitive answer with reference? Thank you!

1.https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-introduction-to-pyspark-ff4284701873

> Try minimizing eager operations: In order for your pipeline to be as scalable as possible, it’s good to avoid eager operations that pull full dataframes into memory. I’ve noticed that reading in CSVs is an eager operation, and my work around is to save the dataframe as parquet and then reload it from parquet to build more scalable pipelines.

Comment: It's a lazy evaluator

Answer (score 6):

After reading the source code it appears read CSV is lazy if inferSchema option is disabled:

> If the schema is not specified using `schema` function and `inferSchema` option is enabled,
> this function goes through the input once to determine the input schema.

> If the schema is not specified using `schema` function and `inferSchema` option is disabled,
> it determines the columns as string types and it reads only the first line to determine the
> names and the number of fields.

> If the enforceSchema is set to `false`, only the CSV header in the first line is checked
> to conform specified or inferred schema.

2021 July edit:
Source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L560

Comment: Can you give your source? I like to understand how this work for other sources than csv